# The for loop is running only once when used under fetch in js

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

This is my script tag in my html file, my for loop with the variable i runs only once when i=0, the line in the code "(response[i].userId)==2" will work if it was
"(response[i].userId)==1" as only "response[0].userId" is equal to 1, it does not seem to loop back after completing the 1st loop(that is when i =0 only runs).

```js
function request(){
  var h=3;
  var k=4;
  var i;
  var j;
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
method: 'GET',
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
})
.then(response => {
    console.log("entered then");
    
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      console.log("entered for loop with i");
      if ((response[i].userId)==2)
      {
        console.log("entered if cond");
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
          console.log("entered for loop with j");
          if ((response[j].id)==k)
          {
            console.log("entered if cond");
            var res=document.getElementById("res");
            res.innerHTML= response[i].userId;
            var resi=document.getElementById("resi");
            resi.innerHTML= response[j].id;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
});
}

request();
```

[output if "(response[i].userId)==1" was in the if condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIOBG.png)

[output if "(response[i].userId)==2" was in the if condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weKS9.png)

Comment: I turned your code into a runnable snippet. But it shows that the loop is functioning as expected. Also your images show that the loop is iterating as expected. Please clarify.

Comment: The loop is running only once for me the i=1 is not getting run cuz then (response[1].userId)==2 would be true and it would enter the if condition

Comment: @LEJ — The live demo in the question shows otherwise.

Comment: i have added images which show my output

Comment: Images that show your output don't help us reproduce the problem. We need an [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Because, all your input response are having userId = 1. For testing purpose, the userId is updated to id. (note this is not advised to be done on front end, but for testing purpose your code is working)

```js
function request(){
  var h=3;
  var k=4;
  var i;
  var j;
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
method: 'GET',
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
})
.then(response => {
    console.log("entered then");
    
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      console.log("entered for loop with i", i);
      (response[i].userId) = response[i].id; // testing purpose only
      if ((response[i].userId)==2)
      {
        console.log("entered if cond");
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
          console.log("entered for loop with j");
          if ((response[j].id)==k)
          {
            console.log("entered if cond");
            var res=document.getElementById("res");
            res.innerHTML= response[i].userId;
            var resi=document.getElementById("resi");
            resi.innerHTML= response[j].id;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
});
}

request();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding your problem, you are thinking that the loop only runs once but that is not true, it runs all 10 items, the issue why it doesnt go inside the if method is because the user id never changes and is always 1 not 2 for response[i] 1--10

Run the below code snippets to see what I mean

```js
function request(){
  var h=3;
  var k=4;
  var i;
  var j;
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
method: 'GET',
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
})
.then(response => {
    console.log("entered then");
 
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      console.log("entered for loop with i: " + i);
      console.log(response[i]);
      if ((response[i].userId)===2)
      {
        console.log("entered if cond");
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
          console.log("entered for loop with j");
          if ((response[j].id)===k)
          {
            console.log("entered if cond");
            var res=document.getElementById("res");
            res.innerHTML= response[i].userId;
            var resi=document.getElementById("resi");
            resi.innerHTML= response[j].id;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
});
}

request();
```

if you are trying to access all the messages inside the user it would be this

```js
function request(){
  var h=3;
  var k=4;
  var i;
  var j;
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
method: 'GET',
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
})
.then(response => {
    console.log("entered then");
 
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      console.log("entered for loop with i: " + i);
      console.log(response[i]);
      if ((response[i].userId)===1)
      {
        console.log("entered if cond");
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
          console.log("entered for loop with j");
          if ((response[j].id)===k)
          {
            console.log("entered if cond");
            var res=document.getElementById("res");
            res.innerHTML= response[i].userId;
            var resi=document.getElementById("resi");
            resi.innerHTML= response[j].id;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
});
}

request();
```

Answer (score 0):

The json placeholder I have used has 10 userId which is equal to 1, so to get to when userId is equal to 2 I will need i to be <=11 to access that, yea stupid mistake i had made